# why to compute distribution when I need to extract the confidential interval of my data?

Tags: distributions, confidence-interval

I need to compute confidence interval for regression intercepts.To summarize:

1\ I extract all intercept of my data based on linear regression `[a1,a2,a3,..,an]`

2\ After that I check the best distribution for them. The result is the parameter distribution output. for example:

```
vonmises distribution params output:
(709.7826236568751, 2.5410432576577704e-14, 1.027676254248482e-10)
```

But now I need to plot the confidential interval for my data. I need to have aplot like this: 
[image]

So I don't understand why to compute distribution params? what is their role to compute confidential inerval? how to plot this confidential interval based on my disstribution outputs?

Answer (score 1):

I'll use linear regression as an example since that is what you seem to be referring to.

Linear regression returns the mean of a conditional distribution.  That mean is the sum to random variables $\beta_0, \beta_1$.

$$y = \beta_0 + \beta_1x$$

In order to obtain CIs, you need estimates of the variance of the mean, which can be expressed in terms of the variance of $\beta_0,\beta_1$.

$$ \operatorname{Var}(y) =  \operatorname{Var}(\beta_0) + x^2 \operatorname{Var}(\beta_1) + 2x\operatorname{Cov}(\beta_0, \beta_1)$$

You need the parameters to fit a CI because you need to know their variance.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. I want to verify that  different steps that I follow are  correct or not?

Comment: Your steps are unclear to me. I can’t comment if they are correct.

Comment: In fact my goal is to compute confidence interval for regression intercepts.

Comment: I edit my question could you please check the edited question

Comment: So do you want a confidence interval for the y intercept, the x intercept, or both?

Comment: I need the CI for x intercepts only; For that I check their distribution.I found that it is vonmises distribution.  What I put in question are the parameter outputs of distribution. As I understand I must to use this parameters to compute the confidence interval